# How to make "-persist" unique for GNUPLOT

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I'm using bash to feed gnuplot from a script. How you pop up only one window? Let say you run

```
#!/bin/bash 
for((i=1;i<6;i++)) do
  echo "plot sin(x)"
done | gnuplot -persist
```

you will get 5 windows of the same plot. Is there an option to get only one?

---

There was a mistake above. That wasn't exactly the kind of run-time i'm doing. Is more like runing the next script, say, 5 times

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "plot sin(x)"
```

I just realized that what I want to do is kill the latest gnuplot process before make the new one.

Sorry for that. I'm sooo tired today :D

Comment: If the plot isn't changing, why are you sending the information 6 times?  (I'm having a hard time coming up with a situation where this makes sense...)

Comment: Also, I've tried your script and it worked fine for me (produced only 1 plot (bash 4.1.5 Ubuntu Linux)).  What version of bash are you using?  What OS?

Comment: You can kill the gnuplot windows with `killall gnuplot_x11` if you're using the x11 terminal.  I'm not sure if -persist works with other terminals...(tested on OS X)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the gnuplot x11 terminal uses a separate program called `gnuplot_x11` for displaying the results.  From the help

```
The `xlib` terminal driver supports the X11 Windows System.  It generates
 gnuplot_x11 commands, but sends them to the output file specified by
 `set output '<filename>'`. `set term x11` is equivalent to
 `set output "|gnuplot_x11 -noevents"; set term xlib.`
 `xlib` takes the same set of options as `x11`.
```

So, if you want to kill plots that are remaining after a `gnuplot -persist`, it should suffice to `killall gnuplot_x11`.

Answer (score 2):

What about the following:

```
  echo `for((i=1;i<6;i++))
  do
    echo 'plot sin(x)'
  done` | gnuplot -persist
```

Comment: I get `gnuplot> plot sin(x) plot sin(x) plot sin(x) plot sin(x) plot sin(x)
                     ^
         line 0: unexpected or unrecognized token`

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the iteration capabilities available in newer versions of Gnuplot (see the section Iteration in the [user's guide](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

In one script one can

```
    echo "set grid" > gpfile
    tail -f  gpfile | gnuplot  '-'
```

then in another process one can write any gnuplot commands  into the gpfile

```
    echo "plot \"whatever\" " >> gpfile
    sleep 3
    echo "replot" >> gpfile
```

...etc

Its useful for realtime process control display,  where some status file

is being updated at intervals.